# Как использовать переменную типа Double, введенную в одном ViewController для расчета в другом?

Tags: ios, swift, переменные, double

Нужно при вводе в TextField переменной перенести ее на другой ViewController.
Перенос типа данных String у меня получился, а вот Double он не хочет использовать.

```
 @objc func doneClicked() {
        view.endEditing(true)

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 6

        if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {


            rasstoyanie = number.doubleValue
        }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var ResultController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
        ResultController.rasstoyanie_result = rasstoyanie
    }
```

И второй VC:

```
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {


    var rasstoyanie_result: Double = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var resulLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        resulLabel = "\(rasstoyanie_result)"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Пишите так:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var resultController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
        resultController.rasstoyanie_result = rasstoyanie
    }
```

2) Используйте camelCase

вместо `rasstoyanie_result` пишите `rasstoyanieResult`

Если вдруг переменная будет равна 0 то проверьте ее перед присваиванием.